# How to Split a huge JSON file in ADLS using ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We read JSON data through API which contains almost 1000 records (JRID) per file and the JSON file gets loaded into the AZURE ADLS container. We load these JSON file from ADLS into the snowflake Variant column for further processing. Some JSON file contains many attributes / expands which results JSON file size > 16MB.  Hence we want to split the each JSON file received through API into multiple small chunks based on JRID which is unique **in ADLS ** and then load these newly created files into the Snowflake stage table for further processing.
Any advice on how to achieve this would be a great help.

JSON file receive as --

```
`{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "uri": "https://abc/JR(233L)",
                    "type": "SFOData.JR"
                },
                "JRId": "233",
                "cust_location": null,
                "createdDateTime": "/Date(1679988071000+0000)/",
                "cust_US": "PH0004",
                "pJRId": null
            },
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "uri": "https://abc/JR(223L)",
                    "type": "SFOData.JR"
                },
                "JRId": "223",
                "cust_location": null,
                "createdDateTime": "/Date(1673385012000+0000)/",
                "cust_US": "KL9037",
                "pJRId": null                
            }
        ]
    }
}`
```

Can we implement this using only **ADF** ??

Thanks

I referred below links -
[ADF Pipeline to Split an a JSON File with array of objects into seperate items in cosmos db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72824588/adf-pipeline-to-split-an-a-json-file-with-array-of-objects-) into-seperate-items-i

https://copyprogramming.com/howto/adf-split-a-json-file-with-an-array-of-objects-into-single-json-files-containing-one-element-in-each

Expecting Output in ADLS container --
233.json
223.json

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75992398/merging-json-files-into-one-and-adding-filename-in-data-before-data-is-merged-us

The above link shows merging of multiple files into one, 
Can there be reverse way (to create multuple files from one JSON file)?